# REST (Jersey) Call Taking Forever Certain Number of Requests

Tags: java, rest, jersey

Basic Info:
REST Request, Using Jersey (Java)

I'm working on a project where there's a list of numbers that refer to an individual item.

The user can click on an item number and the corresponding item/data is loaded and presented.

We're having this odd issue where after about the 14th click or so, (direction is irrelevant), a singular REST call
takes *forever*.

We're talking another 500ms to 1s for each additional click after that 14th (or so) click.
I've been patient enough to drive it up to 15 seconds.

Chrome displays < 2 seconds for the "waiting" portion of the event and 2+ seconds in the receiving state  for *360 bytes*.

Any ideas on what could possible cause this?

I wrote a test page that just hammered the server with dozens and dozens of requests. As expected, the browser prevented more than 6 at a time being loaded.
The individual set of 6 requests behaved normally.

I've also tried making the same REST request sequentially, waiting till one was done, then waiting 500 ms, then calling it again to simulate the user click on an additional item.
Behaved as expected.

There's only two differences between my test page and the actual deployed version.

1) We make 3 ajax calls (2 to the same rest service, one to a different one) that always complete on time. These 3 are finished before the 4th (the trouble one) even begins.

2) We have a "auto" save feature that does the above on a 30 second timer. This never has issues and always completes on time as expected.

Thanks SO community. Been banging my head against this for a couple days now and I'm at my wits end. :P

Answer (score 0):

do you have the access to the server side?

you seen anything unusual in the logs?

Did you try and measuring execution time of the each method in the service tier?

You might want to take a look :

http://codemate.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/cpu-profiling-explained/

Maybe also memory profiling but not necessarily since you don't have the out of memory exception

Comment: I have full access to client and server sides.

Comment: The REST calls consists of one method and a return.toString(); I step over that in the debugger, and wait 12+ seconds per the criteria in the OP